# No numeric types to aggregate in pivot table after changing data to floats

Tags: python, pandas

I need to pivot a dataframe (dfM) which looks something like

```
Task Question Answer analystID
x    a        1      u
y    b        2      i
z    c        3      o
```

at first I thought my pivot

```
 dfM = pd.pivot_table(dfM, index = ['Task', 'Question'], columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = ['Answer'])
```

was getting that error (No numeric types to aggregate) because the numbers under the Answer column might have been strings so I tried

```
dfM.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

but I still ended up getting the same error.

Is there a way I can fix this error?

Comment: Try `dfM.pivot_table(index=['Task', 'Question'], columns='analystID', values='Answer', aggfunc='sum')` - explicitly pass the agg function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert `Answer` column to `int` or `float` only, then remove `[]` from `values` parameter for no `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
dfM['Answer'] = dfM['Answer'].astype(int)
df = pd.pivot_table(dfM, index = ['Task', 'Question'], columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = 'Answer')
print (df)
analystID        i    o    u
Task Question               
x    a         NaN  NaN  1.0
y    b         2.0  NaN  NaN
z    c         NaN  3.0  NaN
```

If first solution failed, there are some non numeric values. So need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace non numeric to `NaN`s.

```
dfM['Answer'] = pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'], errors='coerce')
df = pd.pivot_table(dfM, index = ['Task', 'Question'], columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = 'Answer')
print (df)
analystID        i    o    u
Task Question               
x    a         NaN  NaN  1.0
y    b         2.0  NaN  NaN
z    c         NaN  3.0  NaN
```

One row solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(dfM.assign(Answer=dfM['Answer'].astype(int)), 
                     index = ['Task', 'Question'], 
                     columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = 'Answer')
print (df)
analystID        i    o    u
Task Question               
x    a         NaN  NaN  1.0
y    b         2.0  NaN  NaN
z    c         NaN  3.0  NaN
```

EDIT:

If use parameter `errors='ignore'` and some non numeric value, still get error:

```
print (dfM)
  Task Question Answer analystID
0    x        a      r         u <-first ansswer value was changed to `r`
1    y        b      2         i
2    z        c      3         o

dfM['Answer'] = pd.to_numeric(dfM['Answer'], errors='ignore')
```

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Hey, this seemed to work, but for some reason my questions are now all out of order, is there a possible explanation for this?

Comment: Yes, problem is pivot_tale sorted index and columns. What is number of columns after pivot_table?

Comment: because if not many values, is possible after `pivot_table` use `df = df.reindex(columns=['o','i','u'])`, [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

Comment: and for index `df = df.reindex(index=['x','z','y'], level=0)`

Comment: there are 4 columns after the pivot table, which is what was intended (example didnt show the whole dataset), i also noticed that all the stuff in the answer column turned out to be NaNs

Comment: also when I did the reindex thing i got 
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str

Comment: because index is multiindex, so need `level=0` for specify if first column of index or second need reorder by list.

Comment: there are way too many index numbers for me to list out by hand, 517133 to be exact-- I was also wondering if there was a way to resolve that I got all NaNs in the answer column after the original solution

Comment: Hmmm, not so easy. I try find some solution.

Comment: I have some idea, maybe the best is if create new question with desired output. (I think youe question is perfect, because nice sample and desired output) Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, my english. I think you need add some code to question, because some people on SO hate question without code and starts downvote them ;)

Comment: oops, I think problem is with ordering of data in columns, index. So now I try guess.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reassign your apply statement back to dfM.

```
dfM = dfM.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
dfM = pd.pivot_table(dfM, index = ['Task', 'Question'], columns = 'analystID', 
                     values = ['Answer'])

              Answer          
analystID          i    o    u
Task Question                 
x    a           NaN  NaN  1.0
y    b           2.0  NaN  NaN
z    c           NaN  3.0  NaN
```